# Move sheets into folders which have the same name

Tags: google-apps-script

If you several files and folders in your drive, how would you move the same name file into the same name folder.

i.e.

File Name = Bob, Tom

Folder Name = Bob, Tom

The file 'Bob' should be moved into the folder 'Bob' and the file 'Tom' should be moved into the folder 'Tom'.

Answer (score 0):

<s>GAS has no command for moving files.</s> In order to achieve the file move, after it copied the file to the folder, it removes the source file. Even if both file and folder name are same, this can operate. I prepared 2 scripts.

In the case of existing the copy destination folder :

```
var list = ['Bob', 'Tom'];
for (i in list){
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(list[i]).next();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(list[i]).next(); // existing folder
  var sourcefolder = file.getParents().next();
  folder.addFile(list[i]);
  sourcefolder.removeFile(list[i]);
}
```

In the case of not existing the copy destination folder :

```
var list = ['Bob', 'Tom'];
for (i in list){
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(list[i]).next();
  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(list[i]); // make new folder
  var sourcefolder = file.getParents().next();
  folder.addFile(list[i]);
  sourcefolder.removeFile(list[i]);
}
```

By an advice from @pinoyyid, I got an another method for moving files on Google Drive using GAS. I could notice that "GAS has no command for moving files." is wrong. Thank you so much @pinoyyid.

Another method :

```
var accesstoken = '#####';
var list = ['Bob', 'Tom'];
for (i in list){
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(list[i]).next().getId();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(list[i]).next().getId(); // existing folder
  var parameters = {
    method:'put',
    headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken,
              'uploadType' : 'multipart/related'
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify({'parents': [{id: folder}]}),
    muteHttpExceptions : true
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' + file, parameters); 
}
```

Using access token of Google API OAuth2.0, files on Google Drive can be directly moved.

If you have a folder name list on spreadsheet as shown in an image, you can use following script. The script move a file to a folder. At this time, the file name and folder name are same.

[image]

```
var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('a1:a3').getValues();
for (i in list){
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(list[i][0]).next();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(list[i][0]).next();
  var sourcefolder = file.getParents().next();
  folder.addFile(list[i][0]);
  sourcefolder.removeFile(list[i][0]);
}
```

Comment: your solution will work, but it's not true to say that "GAS has no command for moving files". See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive

Comment: Thank you for your information. I have never known about the file move using GAS. Since I want to study, can I ask you which section to read about it?

Comment: @pinoyyid Updated. Thank you for your advice. I could get a new knowledge.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you. What if the list is in a column of a spreadsheet ? rather than knowing the names of the files/ folders ?

Comment: The list can be retrieved using GAS. And texts of the list can be used as file and folder name.

Comment: I updated sample script, just now. Before updated, the script has copied by making new fine. This script moves files by updating folder of file.

Comment: @pinoyyid The GAS method stated above doesnt work. Would you be able to advice on how to add all the files named 'Bob' into the 'Bob' folder. I.e. multiple files ?

Comment: @Tanaike The GAS method stated above doesnt work. Would you be able to advice on how to add all the files named 'Bob' into the 'Bob' folder. I.e. multiple files ?

Comment: See the first link I posted. You need to use the Advanced Drive service

Comment: @Anjali What files do you have? Can I ask you about the detail? I cannot understand what you really want to do from the information you showed. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike I just want to automatically file things within my drive. The aim of this is that I have a master spreadsheet which lists all the folders within my drive. The script should go through my drive and identify any file with the same name of the first folder and file within the same folder and loop through the list. An example would be : The first row of the spreadsheet it Alpha, my drive has an existing folder called Alpha and several documents within my drive called Alpha. So one folder and multiple files with the same name Alpha. ...

Comment: @Tanaike  In this case the script should find all the Alpha file and file it within the folder Alpha

Comment: @Anjali I understand as follows. You have a spreadsheet included only folder names. In the drive, there are some files of file name with folder name. The file name is same to folder name. And there are any files with same file name. You want to move files corresponding to folder name to the folder with same name. If I misunderstand, can I see the sample spreadsheet and file names?

Comment: @Anjali Can I ask you about your script and sheet?